# ReferenceError: audio is not defined

Tags: jquery, html, audio, meteor

I'm building an audio player in Meteor for a client.

I'm getting an error when I try to create an audio object. I'm using the following code. Any idea why this is happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Define Audio
song = new Audio('/audio/waitforme.mp3');

// Define Play
play = $('#playicon');

$(function() {
$('#playicon').on("click", function() {
e.preventDefault();
song.play();
})
});


ReferenceError: Audio is not defined
    at AlannaSite.js:2:14
    at AlannaSite.js:12:4
    at /Users/CorrinSite/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/AriKamin/.meteor/packages/meteor-        tool/.1.1.9.1sd3e7j++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /Users/CorrinSite/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
```

Comment: Actually it was originally set as Audio() not audio() and that error was still there.

Comment: Then [edit] your question, with the proper error message and the proper code. As it is, the only answer is that one.

Comment: alright, changed it. Get the same error with Audio instead of "audio".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think there's a misconception here. You have the right code, but it's running in a different context.

In the case of Meteor, the NodeJS back-end is also running your 'client-side' code. NodeJS doesn't have support for the Audio API that you're using, sadly, but your browser does.

This code serving and running in both the client-side and server-side can get a bit confusing to know the lines between client + server, especially when Meteor tries to blur those lines!

I would look up Meteor's architecture so you can best structure your code to target the 'client-end' vs. 'back-end' environments. A great article is here: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/what-goes-where/

Basically, Meteor provides two directories that you can use to specifically target the client or server. You can place files in `/client` or `/server` and it will be handled for you.

For something quick or for a file that is used in both contexts, the Meteor docs explains a boolean flag called `Meteor.isClient` or `Meteor.isServer` that you can use to mark code to be ran only on the client-side / server-side: http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-isClient

Comment: Cool. I wasn't aware the Meteor.isClient / isServer was necessary for all functions (mostly just used it with helpers and pub / sub before). Will definitely drop that in, then close the question if it works.

Answer (score 4):

This will compile on the server-side:

```js
    if(typeof Audio != "undefined") {
      // Browser-only code
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

In ReactJS with hooks, you can use also an expression for Audio(HTMLElements):

```
const [audio] = useState(typeof Audio !== "undefined" && new Audio(URL));
audio.play()
```

Hope I could help, somehow :)

Comment: Super clean implementation! 
Here's the TS version I ended up using.
`const [audio] = React.useState<HTMLAudioElement | null>(typeof Audio !== 'undefined' ? new Audio(URL) : null)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this code in a Node.js environment, you won't have direct access to the HTML5 Audio API, which is a client-side feature available in web browsers. In a Node.js server, you typically don't have access to client-side features like audio playback.

If you want to work with audio files in a Node.js environment, you can use external libraries like "node-wav-player" or "node-speaker" for audio playback or "node-lame" for audio encoding and decoding. These libraries are designed for server-side audio processing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34800062)