# React testing with Enzyme/Mocha - Audio is not defined

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, enzyme

I am trying to build a test suite for my react application. A component in the application uses `Audio`:

```
const audio = new Audio('beep.wav');
audio.play();
```

which works in the browser but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757854/referenceerror-audio-is-not-defined), is not on node.js. So when I use enzyme to try to render the component it gives an error:

```
ReferenceError: Audio is not defined
```

I am new to testing, but is there a way to get around this? Can I somehow mock an object to take `Audio`'s place? I am new to font-end/javascript unit testing so I am still trying to learn the tricks.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options.

1. Pass Audio object into your testing component as property + during test, you will create [Sinon's stub or spy](http://sinonjs.org/) and pass it to the component as fake dependency.
2. [Since version 9.3.0, jsDOM seem to support Audio constructor](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/blob/13b2326b57ec621c4b75a64966ea23d89d8fce99/Changelog.md#930). So you can [simulate browser environment via jsDOM](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) in your test.